# Java FX Web View not displaying Chinese characters

Tags: java, javafx, webview, character-encoding

I am working on building a browser like Application using Java FX technology. So I have a webview and a web engine that does the loading of the application. Since our product is available in Multiple regions we have to support internationalization. The problem is the response coming from server is correct with all the required Locale specific text. However when dispalyed in the web view those characters are missing. This is happening specifically for Chinese Locale. I have explicitly set the Char encoding to UTF-8 in the JVM. Still the problem persists. Can anyone please give me any insight into what could be the problem?

Thanks in Advance
Boris

Comment: I am reading the header text from the html response back from the server in the following way -

Comment: The webview uses WebKit, same as Chrome. It has nothing to do with Java in fact. Some Chinese sites may assume the default locale is UTF-8, or GBK (simplified Chinese) or Big5 (traditional Chinese). If you test them on Windows with IE, such would be assumed depending on Windows region or fallback charset. The easiest way to be sure is to open such site in your Chrome, or open Chinese version of Goggle in webview.

Comment: Are the paged correctly decoded? If you're not seeing very strange characters but instead lots of empty ones, it might be the fonts.

Comment: I have set the default encoding to UTF-8. Also in the response returned from the server I can see the Letters. However when displayed in the web view panel, the characters are missing.

Comment: So it might be the fonts or font names (better to be in english)? Have you tried showing Chinese website? I tested it with "Ensemble" sample and it's working here (I have all the fonts installed). Have you tried your site with Google Chrome? Or showing other chinese sites your webview panel?

Comment: Yes. My application is displaying properly in IE and chrome. Also webview is able to display Google.com in chinese. Do I ave to install some fonts separately??

Comment: Can you copy&paste the invisible text to other applications such as Word? Can you show part of the source / response header and screenshot of webpage where chinese text is invisible? One possibility is the website does not specify fallback fonts such as sans-serif and webview fails to find a proper font for it.

Comment: I tried copying the invisible text and pasting it in a Word Document. I am able to do it. The text is getting copied correctly. I am guessing some issue with the font for the webview.

Comment: Yes it's the font. Is that Calibri or other new font since Vista? For Windows Vista+ the font-family in CSS needs to be something like Calibri, ..., Microsoft JhengHei, Microsoft YaHei, Sans-Serif. So that characters of Traditional and Simplified Chinese can be rendered. And San-Serif is the fallback for characters not existing in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Azul Zulu JDK (the version that has Javafx embedded) as your SDK in your project structure. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try to use Liberica JDK. It has Full, Standard and Lite packages for different use cases. Full one includes up-to-date OpenJFX binaries integrated with the JDK. https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/ That should resolve your issue.