# JavaFX 8 HTMLeditor cannot show 4-byte unicode characters

Tags: javafx, unicode

I added a HTMLeditor in my JavaFX 8 program:
I need to display some 4-byte unicode characters in it.

```
@FXML
private HTMLEditor htmlEditor;

@FXML
void initialize() {

    htmlEditor.setHtmlText("<html><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"></head><body></body></html>");

}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I do the same in JavaFX WebView and the result is the same.
Is there any way to show the 4-byte unicode characters correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: Could be the encoding, could be the font.  See: [Java FX Web View not displaying Chinese characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204575/java-fx-web-view-not-displaying-chinese-characters), [JavaFX Webview bad encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484117/javafx-webview-bad-encoding).  JavaFX 8 is obsolete, you could also try a recent JavaFX version, e.g. 17.0.2+

Comment: I tried this with OpenJDK 17.0.2, JavaFX 17.0.2 on a Mac OS X 12.1 and it had the same output.  Also, if you paste in the character, it displays the character and then a square box character after it.  So the WebView can display the character.  I don't know how to get rid of the additional square box on copy and paste, nor how to provide an input string in setHtmlText that will display the character.  [Encoding info for the character](https://decodeunicode.org/en/u+21596).  Replacing with the character with UTF-16 encoded constant `\uD845\uDD96`, does not help.

Comment: What happens using `<body>&#x21596;</body>` instead of `<body></body>`? Displayed 6 replacement characters (like 3 bytes for each surrogate in `\ud845\udd96`)…

Comment: It works by using <body>&#x21596;</body>. But the problem is, I added the HTMLeditor for text editing. I won't actually open a console and input the setHtmlText command. Both HTMLeditor and WebView won't recognize those characters if I input in GUI.

Comment: BTW, can you tell me how to convert a UTF-8 characters into the code you provided using command line? Thanks.

Comment: I searched myself the code you provided is called HTML entry and the libraries for conversion are rare. I can barely find two but both can only support 3 byte unicode characters but not 4. I also tried escapeHTML4 in Amazon's library but it doesn't work too.